# DJANGO - экспорт данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Есть проект на Django, в процессе работы в базу данных вручную были добавлены несколько таблиц для совместимости со старой версией проекта.

Сейчас решился на переезд с SQLite на PostgreSQL и есть ошибка:

1. Если делаю экспорт как есть - файл сохраняется, но при этом в не создается структура сторонних таблиц и при загрузке на новый сервер выдается ошибка т.к. таблиц нет

   ```
   django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: Problem installing fixture '/Users/user/python2/datadump.json': Could not load products.Params(pk=540): relation "cms_params" does not exist
   LINE 1: UPDATE "cms_params" SET "cat_id" = 92, "parent_id" = 0, "sho...
   ```
2. Удаляю из SQLite лишние таблицы, делаю экспорт и получаю ошибку:

   ```
   python3 manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json
   CommandError: Unable to serialize database: no such table: cms_params
   ```

   если добавляю `--exclude=table_name`, то будет ошибка

   ```
   CommandError: No installed app with label 'cms_params'.
   ```

Как это обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Скорее всего вы что то не то удалили.
Вам надо пересоздать базу, с нуля применить все миграции. Если такой возможности нет и в базе уже есть данные которые вам нужны то попробуйте создать отдельную базу и приминить все миграции, после чего восстановить всне необходимые таблицы в продакшен базе в ручную.
И проверьте `INSTALLED_APPS` в `settings.py` там должен быть прописан ваш app.
Еще можно проверить все ли миграции применены.
`python manage.py showmigrations`
Подробнее тут https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-showmigrations